# Change MAMP nginx user

Tags: nginx, mamp

When I change nginx user

user                         root admin;

worker_processes             2;

in nginx.conf it will reset to default value root admin after restarting MAMP. How I change it correctly...

Answer (score 0):

***NGINX***

edit nginx.conf and set user to ***hereuser hereuser;***

***PHP-FPM***

Edit php-fpm.conf and set user and group to heregroup.

Comment: Still user reset to root admin;

Where I can find the php-fpm.conf file related to MAMP